# Manual resize and drag bootstrap 3 modals

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

is possible to manual resize modal windows from bootstrap 3
 with mouse and to drag them all over in your workspace?
I want that when a modal is opening to have the possibility to resize manual how I want.
Is possible to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible? yes. Elegant? no.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's hard to add all the options that are not native on bootstrap modal.

You can maybe use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ and stylize it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
     });
</script>
```

If you really want to use bootstrap, try to implement [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) on jQuery UI

> The ability to work side-by-side with jQuery UI (something which
>   caused a number of widgets to break visually) The ability to theme
>   jQuery UI widgets using Bootstrap styles. Whilst I love jQuery UI, I
>   (like others) find some of the current themes to look a little dated.
>   My hope is that this theme provides a decent alternative for others
>   that feel the same. To clarify, this project doesn't aim or intend to
>   replace Twitter Bootstrap. It merely provides a jQuery UI-compatible
>   theme inspired by Bootstrap's design. It also provides a version of
>   Bootstrap CSS with a few (minor) sections commented out which enable
>   the theme to work along-side it.

Comment: Why? With dialog, you can move it and resize it, no?

Comment: Apparently is not working with .dialog. I have tested with this:  <script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>

Comment: But have you add the HTML? Maybe you havn't add the jquery UI lib? See my example and you can view the source code in the dialog link. The jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mB6B7/4/

Comment: Is all set, maybe because of bootstrao scripts is not working

Comment: You can't mix two lib easily. If you use dialog from jQuery UI, you can't use modal from bootstrap and conversely.

Comment: Yes, but my question was how to do that for bootstrap modals, I know that is not possible. Ty anymay.

Comment: All is possible but the problem it's that can create a lot of error and conflict.. And spend time to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery UI Bootstrap: http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/components.html#dialog
-dialog section.